# Xamarin Google Play Services Component Turn Based Multiplayer Example

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, monogame

Does anyone have an example of Turn-Based Multiplayer using the Google Play Services Component? I haven't even been able to get an app to compile with the newer versions (v16.0) of the Component (see [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16042/google-play-services-component-gingerbread-cannot-find-listener-classes-compiler-error#latest)) and I am trying to figure out if anyone has actually got this thing to work before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating my own example of Turn Based Multiplayer game using:

- Android
- MonoGame.Android
- Xamarin
- Google Player Services

Full source can be found here:

https://github.com/mhughson/mbhxamarintbmpdemo

Should be a decent jumping off point for others hopefully.